# Obtain static maps copyright string

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I know I can use Google static maps api to return an image of a location but can it also return the copyright text as a string?

I know that the image returned already contains the copyright string but I am showing the images in a 3d environment and the shadows often make the text unreadable so if I had the copyright as a string I can display a window with the text on it.

I am doing this to abide by Google's copyright terms.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your effort in complying with the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#9-license-requirements), especially the section 9.4.

For now, there isn't available any feature with this capability. I strongly recommend you to publish a [Feature Request in the Static Maps section](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Static%20Maps%20-%20Feature%20Request)
at the public [Issue Tracker of Google Maps APIs](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/).